# Questions regarding Azure,web sites, IntelliTrace and filtering calls

Tags: debugging, azure, visual-studio-2013, intellitrace

I have never really tried IntelliTrace before, but I am currently having a problem with a bug within one of my applications and I cant really re-produce the bug on my local-machine since it only seems to show up in my QA environment that's hosted on Azure. Another problem is that I am not allowed to "halt" the QA environment since I have users currently doing some evaluation.. and the last problem is.. that the bug seems to be very random..
So I stumbled upon IntelliTrace.. and I have a few questions.. I have searched the web but I cant really find any clear answers..

First question:
Does IntelliTrace record all the requests and responses that's made (basically will it log all the values for my objects for all requests that done so its more or less like "live-debugging" in the end.?)..

Last question:
If it does log all the request code execution and their values within variables and objects and such, is there anyway to sort of filter the IntelliTrace down to a specific time.. as it seems to be now.. all the calls are just listed from top to bottom,, but what if Im actually only interested of the calls that has been made during 2014-08-26 01:17 - 2014-08-26 01:27?.. is there a way of doing that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by “halt the QA environment”, but note that to use IntelliTrace you need to launch the application instead of attaching to it.
If you are able to re-launch the application with "events and calls" mode, method calls will be recorded and parameters will be collected, though there are limitations how much it will collect.
And no, you can't filter the collected calls by time at least for current version of Visual Studio.

HTH.